# Relation between the spin of a field and the way charges interact

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-spin, field-theory, interactions, higher-spin

When solving the problems of V. Rubakov's "*Classical Theory of Gauge fields*" book, I encountered the following phenomenon:

- For a real scalar fields (**spin 0**) $\phi$, if we consider the action with source $\rho(\overrightarrow{x},t)$,
  $$S=\int d^4x \left\{ \frac{1}{2}\partial_\mu\phi\partial^\mu\phi-\frac{m^2}{2}\phi^2+\rho\phi\right\}, $$
  and that we take the source associated to two charges $q_1$ and $q_2$ in $\overrightarrow{x}_1$ and $\overrightarrow{x}_2$,
  $$ \rho(t,\overrightarrow{x}) = -q_1\delta^{(3)}(\overrightarrow{x}-\overrightarrow{x}_1)-q_2\delta^{(3)}(\overrightarrow{x}-\overrightarrow{x}_2),$$
  then the energy of interaction of those charges (obtained by extracting the divergent terms of the Hamiltonian) decreases when $|\overrightarrow{x}_1-\overrightarrow{x}_2|$ decreases if $q_1q_2>0$. In other words, **charges of the same sign attract each other**.
- For a (real) vector field (**spin 1**) $A_\mu$, if we consider the action with source $j^\mu(\overrightarrow{x},t)$,
  $$S=\int d^4x \left\{ -\frac{1}{4}F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}-ej_\mu A^\mu\right\}, $$
  with $F_{\mu\nu}=\partial_\mu A_\nu-\partial_\nu A_\mu$,
  and that we take the source associated to two charges $q_1$ and $q_2$ in $\overrightarrow{x}_1$ and $\overrightarrow{x}_2$,
  \begin{align}
              j_0(t,\overrightarrow{x}) &= -q_1\delta^{(3)}(\overrightarrow{x}-\overrightarrow{x}_1)-q_2\delta^{(3)}(\overrightarrow{x}-\overrightarrow{x}_2), \\
              j_i(t,\overrightarrow{x}) &= 0,
  \end{align}
  then the energy of interaction of those charges (obtained in the same way) decreases when $|\overrightarrow{x}_1-\overrightarrow{x}_2|$ increases if $q_1q_2>0$. In other words, **charges of the same sign repulse each other**. As in well-known electromagnetsim.
- For a **spin 2** field (the metric for example), the behavior switch again: **charges of the same sign attract each other**. This is pretty intuitive when when it comes to gravity.

The pattern seems pretty clear.

1. What is the fundamental reason for this to happend?
2. What about half-integer spin fields?
3. Does it continue for higher (than 2) spin fields?  I heard that higher spin fields are much more difficult and that is was still not much understood. Why is that?

Comment: I recommend checking section $2.3.5$ of  Padmanabhan's book, 
 Gravitation, where he discusses this issue specifically.

Comment: For your third question, see [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/14932/why-do-we-not-have-spin-greater-than-2)

Comment: A feature of charge conjugation on integral spin fields.

Comment: [Near duplicate](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/433678/why-is-boson-spin-number-related-to-attraction-and-repulsion?rq=1).