# If quantum spin is intrinsic then how does it affects like charges repel opposite attracts?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, forces, quantum-spin

I was looking at the potential of interaction of an electron and a positron in a Feynman's diagram, if one side is negative and the other is positive there is an attractive force between the two particles, ok simple math I think I got it! Now how does this intrinsic property allows the particle to pull and push another particle and where does the conservation of momentum kicks in? I believe momentum is conserved when the forces you applied to the particle becomes friction and transfer a portion to the other particle but how is it connected to quantum spin?

For clarification: picture 2 electrons already repelling each other at a distance, if I apply a force to push 1 of them closer to the other then by virtue of conservation of momentum the other electron must accelerate in opposite direction. But this is not related to how quantum spins allow particle to be able to push and pull each other in the first place!

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Why is boson spin number related to attraction and repulsion?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/433678/)

Answer (score 1):

> I was looking at the potential of interaction of an electron and a positron in a Feynman's diagram, if one side is negative and the other is positive there is an attractive force between the two particles,

Electrons and positrons and Feynman diagrams belong to the quantum frame, whereas your "attractive force"  is in the classical electromagnetic interactions . The Coulomb potential at the quantum level controls the wavefunctions describing the system, the type and number of Feynman diagrams needed to **compute the probabilities of interaction**.

> Now how does this intrinsic property allows the particle to pull and push another particle and where does the conservation of momentum kicks in? I believe momentum is conserved when the forces you applied to the particle becomes friction and transfer a portion to the other particle but how is it connected to quantum spin?

This is again a classical picture you describe There is no friction and  push-and pull at the quantum level. Interactions are described by Feynman diagrams.

> For clarification: picture 2 electrons already repelling each other at a distance, if I apply a force to push 1 of them closer to the other then by virtue of conservation of momentum the other electron must accelerate in opposite direction.

You are talking in the classical frame. [Here is the first order](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Particles/expar.html) Feynman diagram of electron repulsion:

[image: ee]

If you  apply a force on one of the incoming electrons different,new, diagrams are needed to describe the interaction at the quantum level.

> But this is not related to how quantum spins allow particle to be able to push and pull each other in the first place!

and this is a completely confused statement of how spins affect interactions.