# Relation of spin and force of bosons

Tags: quantum-field-theory, forces, particle-physics, quantum-spin, bosons

Why can odd spin bosons (gluons, photons) both repel and attract, but even spin bosons (gravitons) can only do one or the other?  Does the Higgs boson fit this rule, i.e. does it mediate a force that is only attractive or only repulsive?

Comment: related https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/621152/how-do-bosons-cause-two-particles-to-attract-why-doesnt-the-exchange-always-re

Comment: See related posts (and links therein): https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/433678/44126, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/77196/44126, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/67285/44126, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/84970/44126