# Have we ever observed electron in gravitational interaction?

Tags: gravity, electrons, antimatter

So, as the title suggests have we ever observed electron in gravitational interaction? If we did have we ever observed a positron (or any other antiparticle) in gravitational interaction? Is there any difference between particle and antiparticle in gravity?

Comment: Would solar wind being deviated by gravitational effects count?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/139545/2451 More on [gravity of anti-matter](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gravity+antimatter).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is half way between answer and comment: the main aim is to direct you to weak equivalence principle tests as one area where such questions are explored.

Experiments to test the equivalence principle are able to detect many aspects of gravity. For example, if the electron had a gravitational interaction different from the one implied by its inertial mass, then this could in principle show up in a weak equivalence principle test, and I think existing experiments are sensitive enough to rule this out quite thoroughly.

Answer (score 2):

Two electrons "touching each other" will gravitationally attract each other with $$G \frac {m_e^{~2}}{(2~r_e)^2} \approx 10^{−42}~\text{N}$$ force. Needles to say that gravitationally interacting elementary particles is out-of-scope of today's (and tomorrow's) research technologies. Add Coulomb force with a lot higher repelling force magnitude, Heisenberg uncertainty principle, which could mess-up interaction energy temporarily and you'll see that it's only possible to see gravitational interaction of HUGE gravity sources like merging black holes, etc.

**EDIT**

More real scenario is to measure particle interaction with Earth gravitational field. For example if say, neutron in a particle accelerator would be accelerated to $v=0.99999999999999999~c$ speed, then per

$$ G \frac {m_n \cdot M_{earth}}{\sqrt{1−(v/c)^{^2}}~R_{earth}^2} \approx 10^{−18}~\text{N}$$

it will experience $1aN~(\text{ato-Newton})$ micro force towards Earth center. This may or may not be measured, but measuring threshold of this scheme is certainly lower than in direct particle-to-particle case.

Finally, indirectly we already know that particles are affected by Earth gravitational field. Consider air density equation vs altitude [barometric formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barometric_formula#Density_equations):

$$ \rho =\rho _{b}\exp \left[{\frac {-g_{0}M\left(h-h_{b}\right)}{R^{*}T_{b}}}\right] $$

Notice gravitational potential energy term $\to g_{0}M\Delta h$, so air get's more sparse up the hills (or higher in atmosphere), right? It is so because air molecules statistical average kinetic energy (term $T_b$ related to air temperature) can't withstand crushing force of Earth gravity, so air molecules simply tend to group more densely by the Earth surface. If molecules would not experience own weight force, then in an isothermal atmosphere would be $\rho = \text{const}$, besides without a stopping gravity, air would quickly evaporate into an outer-space, leaving Earth without atmosphere.

Comment: This does not logically rule out a clever way to infer that the electron has some gravitational interaction. Something could potentially be done with a large number of electrons. I don't know what, but that is besides the point - simply the force between nearby electrons does not rule out the detectability of a gravitational interaction between electrons in general.

Comment: It rules out gravitational interaction detection between **single** elementary particles like electron, neutron, etc. I though that OP was asking exactly about that. Otherwise,- sure that single particles could be detected falling towards massive gravitartional source like Earth center, i.e. maybe particle beam bending from a straight line could be detected in presence of stong gravity field. But that is not particle-to-particle gravitational interaction. Question is what OP is exactly hoping for.

Comment: For experimental evidence of quantized neutron states in Earth's gravitational field, see [this answer and links therein](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/130665/44126). As you say here, gravitation between charged particles is going to be terrifically hard to measure.

Comment: @rob Thanks, cool link. It especially was interesting to read about neutron interferometer driven by gravitational potential energy.

Comment: Regarding the relativistic neutron example, I just did a calculation using Schwarzschild spacetime to model the Earth's gravitational field. With the Lorentz factor as above, and taking a circular trajectory with the circumference of CERN, I still get 9.8m/s^2 as the acceleration in the radial direction. The mass, not "relativistic mass", times this is the force needed to resist gravity

Comment: Also, I suspect the Equivalence Principle would apply?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, the charge of the electron was originally measured with the help of gravity. Oil drops were blown in a small device with an upward magnetic field, and electrons were sitting on the top of the oil drops. There is a relation between the charge sitting on the oil vs the mass of the oil drop, that you can get if you measure the "falling speed" of the oil drops. It turns out, that the observed values are clearly quantized, and the corresponding factor is the electron's charge. Its a very old measurement by Millikan, who got nobel prize for it. We repeated it in the lab during my BSc. It was one of the fun lab sittings.

Comment: This is incorrect. The mass in the Millikan experiment is the mass of an aerosol droplet. The charge-to-mass ratio for the electron was measured using curvature of cathode rays in a magnetic field (also a cool college-level experiment).

Comment: Indeed it measures the charge on the electron using basic equipment. It is a key experiment of gravity interacting with electrons.

Comment: @rob thanks, corrected my mistake! I remembered badly the name, it was some time ago!

Answer (score 2):

Individual neutrons and atoms have been observed in free-fall as has been [anti-hydrogen](https://www.nature.com/articles/nphys2624).  There are three approaches: generate cold beams (i.e. low momentum spread), follow the trajectories; trap the particles, then turn off the trap and watch them fall; trap them, then use a laser to kick them upward (aka [atomic fountains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_fountain)), and study macroscopic properties such as the height that they reach or, with lower excitations, the resulting absorption spectra, see e.g. [here](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/free-falling-atoms-offer/).  Electrons, or charged particles in general, are usually easier to study than neutral particles because electromagnetic fields are so easy to produce. But in this case any electrical field would perturb the measurement because of the relative weakness of gravity, so actually experiments with neutral particles (or atoms) are simpler.  One way around that is to use singly-ionized heavy atoms, where experiments have been [suggested](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1367-2630/17/3/035011)

Answer (score 1):

Consider the equivalence principle tests by the Kasevich group at Stanford. Here is [a blog-level introduction](https://web.stanford.edu/group/kasevich/cgi-bin/wordpress/?page_id=11), and a [bibliography](https://web.stanford.edu/group/kasevich/cgi-bin/wordpress/?page_id=71#EP).

The method is to drop ultra-cold clouds of rubidium-85 and -87 atoms, and look for interference effects. They claim a goal precision of $10^{-15}g$ difference in acceleration between the two species, and in [this 2020 publication](https://arxiv.org/abs/2005.11624) find no equivalence principle violations at the part-per-trillion level.

It's not immediately obvious (to me, skimming the linked paper) whether the rubidium experiments would count as a measurement of gravitation *on electrons*, since the number of (protons plus electrons) is the same in the two isotopes and the precision of the measurement arises from the differential technique. You can probably mine references-of-references until you come to a recent literature review.

The gravitational behavior of antimatter is the subject of several experiments using the cold antihydrogen source at CERN; see [this Wikipedia article and links therein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antiproton_Decelerator#AD_experiments).