# How to solve for a particle in a triangular well?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, electric-fields, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation

I am currently trying to solve the problem of a particle confined within an infinite well subject to a linear electric field (i.e. triangular well). This entails solving the Schrodinger equation
$$-\frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\partial^2_x\psi_n(x) + (V_l(x) +V_w(x)) \psi_n(x) = E_n \psi_n(x)$$
where $V_l(x) = q \varepsilon x $ (with $q$ and $\varepsilon$ being the elementary charge and amplitude of the electric field respectively) and $V_w(0>x>L) \to \infty$ (0 otherwise).

By defining the variable $z \equiv \left(\frac{2mq\varepsilon}{\hbar^2} \right)^{1/3}\left(x-\frac{E_n}{q\varepsilon} \right)$, the above Schrodinger equation (for $0<x<L$) becomes of the form

$$\partial_z^2\psi_n-z\psi_n=0.$$
The above has the general solution $\psi_n(z) = a Ai(z) + b Bi(z)$.

If the particle was not confined within a well (i.e. $V_w(x) = 0$ everywhere), one could set $b=0$ since $Bi(z)\to \infty$ as $z\to \infty$, and the wave function would not be normalizable otherwise. In this case, the energies $E_n$ can be easily found by solving for $Ai(z)=0$. After these are found, it is then easy to compute the normalization condition that would return an expression for $a$.

However, I am not sure that the argument $b=0$ can be made for the case in which the particle is indeed confined within an infinite well of finite length. This complicates the problem and I am not sure how I should proceed to find the energies $E_n$ and normalization constants $a$ and $b$. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: This sounds a bit like a homework problem. Are you familiar with the significance of continuity in solutions to the time independent Schrödinger equation?

Comment: Note that the linear potential also describes a particle traveling horizontally under the influence of gravity. If the particle is constrained to stay between two horizontal reflectors, the potential becomes an infinite well with a linear floor — exactly the problem you are describing.  That experiment has been done using neutrons; see [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/130665/44126) for links to the literature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I would approach it.  I'll use units where $m = q\epsilon = \hbar = 1$ for notational simplicity.

First, use a temporary normalization where $a = 1$.  We'll fix the overall normalization later.

The boundary conditions on your function are
\begin{align*}
x &= 0: && \text{Ai}(-E_n) + b \,\text{Bi}(-E_n) = 0 \\
x &= L: && \text{Ai}(L-E_n) + b \,\text{Bi}(L-E_n) = 0
\end{align*}
This is a set of two equations and two unknowns in $b$ & $E_n$, and so should have a discrete solution set.  It may be numerically hard to find, but it should exist.  For example, here's what it looks like for $L = 4$;  the blue contours represent the solutions to the first condition, while the yellow contours represent the solutions to the second condition.

[image]

We can see that these contours intersect at points corresponding to $E_n \approx 2.4, 4.5$, and $7.6$, with corresponding values of $b$.  The values read off from the graphs can then be refined with numerical root-finding techniques.

Finally, once $b$ has been found, you would normalize the overall wavefunctions in the usual way. This will probably require numerical integration.

**EDIT:**  A better parametrization scheme would be to set $a = c \cos \theta$ and $b = c \sin \theta,$ with $0 \leq \theta < \pi$. If you set $a = 1$ by fiat, then my original method risks missing solutions where $b \gg a$.  The equations above then become a system in $\theta$ and $E_n$, and $c$ can be fixed by the normalization constraint once these values are found.

Comment: thank you for the clear answer. However, I am not really getting the edit. How would your approach cause problems in the case $b\gg a$?

Comment: @Oti:  If you're just making a plot like the one I made above, it has to be over a finite range of $b$, and it's possible that there are intersections outside the range of $b$ values that you plotted.  The revised parametrization (with $c$ and $\theta$) allows you to plot a finite range of $\theta$ and more easily find all of the intersections.

Comment: I see what you mean, thank you.

Comment: Regarding root finding methods: as of now I have implemented my own approach on python to do this. This is because all existing packages either return only one set of $\{E, \theta\}$ (most of the times without even specifying whether this is for the lowest possible $E$-value) or they do not allow to specify an interval for the search (leading to solutions where $E<0$. My approach works by finding the intersection between the contour curves you plot above, but for high precision this requires a fine discretization of my parameter space. Do you have any suggestion on how I could improve on this?

Comment: @Oti: I don't have a lot of experience with Python, unfortunately. You might try asking that as a new question over on [scicomp.se].

Comment: One last thing. I have now the need to find a solution for $\theta$ when E = 0. The way I am approaching this is to then combine the system of two equations into one as $ a (Ai(E=0,z=0) - Ai(E=0,z=L)) + b (Bi(E=0,z=0) - Bi(E=0,z=L)) = 0$. I then solve this equation for $\theta$. Do you think this is a good way of combining my boundary conditions? I thought it should be, however my code is failing at finding correct values for $\theta$. This could be caused by some bugs in the code, but as I am having problems finding any, I am left wondering whether I am missing something.

Comment: @Oti:  Since $V \geq 0$ for the allowed particle range, you'll have $\langle V \rangle > 0$ for any state.  Moreover, the kinetic energy operator is strictly positive, so you're going to have $\langle E \rangle > 0$ for any state. This means that there cannot be an energy eigenstate with $E = 0$.