# Shouldn't dark energy be considered a fifth fundamental force?

Tags: forces, terminology, dark-energy, interactions

As everyone knows from the Standard Model, there are 4 fundamental forces that describe the Universe. But isn't the dark energy, the force that makes the universe expand, different from them?

Maybe Higgs particle is a sixth fundamental force?

Comment: Dark energy makes the universe expand through its gravitational effects. No new force here.

Comment: possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/1080/84967

Comment: But gravity attracts while darkenergy makes the universe expand. How can they be the same force if they do opposite things

Comment: Some models of dark energy do postulate a new type of force field, they even call it ["quintessence"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quintessence_(physics)) (fifth element). However, the more traditional view is that it is a version of the cosmological constant, i.e. a correction to Einstein's field equations for gravity. Higgs field is [not considered to be fundamental](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/1085/65263).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, dark energy don't make the universe expand. It is what is causing the expansion **to accelerate**.

Secondly, we don't know enough about dark energy to put it under an umbrella yet. Now, Gravity is an attraction force in current conditions. We have theories where gravity was a repelling force in the early universe that made our closed Universe to burst. Read up Dr. Lawrence Krauss's - A Universe from Nothing.

Higgs particle is a boson, can't be a force. What's next on your list... Fermion?

Most important thing is that you can't just call everything a force. The units/dimension must match. Energy and force and particles are totally different things.

Comment: The spirit of the question I believe was not literally singling out the "higgs boson" as a particle but vaguely referring to the "higgs field" and its interaction with other particles. Taken this way: it seems most people agree that the "higgs interaction" is a new fifth fundamental force see here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/1080/why-isnt-higgs-coupling-considered-a-fifth-fundamental-force#:~:text=Not%20only%20is%20the%20Higgs,violating%20conservation%20of%20mass%2Fenergy.

Comment: Despite my rebuttal I still agree with your primary answer of "lets not call dark energy a new force until we understand it"

Comment: @frogeyedpeas Well, gravity is considered as one of the 4 fundamental forces but if we are really trying to be super technical, then according to the general theory of relativity, gravity itself is not a force. A great explanation is given by Veritasium: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XRr1kaXKBsU

Answer (score 0):

It is very possible that it is a fundamental force. It is also very possible that it is not. Dark energy may bot be energy in any way so arguments about energy being different than forces are not logical. We don't know what it is. But since we don't know what it is we can't classify it as anything, really.