# Is there a fifth fundamental force?

Tags: forces, higgs, interactions

When particle physicists said *interaction*, I interpreted it as *force*.

So, when I heard that elementary particles interact with the Higgs field, which confers them with mass, I thought this must be a force as well. But, particle physicists make it clear that there are only *four* fundamental forces. So is the **Higgs force** the *fifth* force?

I checked up on some more information. So, if interaction with Higgs field, flips the chirality of a lepton, then surely this chirality flipping force is the **fifth fundamental force**, is it not?

**Edit**: Though the linked question is similar to my question, the answers there are a bit *too technical* for me. Even the question is worded in a more mature way. There is no way I can understand the answers there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why isn't Higgs coupling considered a fifth fundamental force?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/1080/)

Comment: *"This question has been asked before and already has an answer. If those answers do not fully address your question*, ***please ask a new question***." Isn't that what this person tried to do? The answers for the other question didn't fully address their question (and they said as much in their question) so they asked a new question here. So why lock the question? How does someone resolve this to get an answer that is acceptable to them?